# How can I move the Downloads toolbar button in Safari 5.1 and newer on OS X?

Tags: macos, safari, ui, customization

In Safari 5.1 on my Mac, the Downloads button appears on the toolbar at the right of the search bar when you download a file for the first time:

[image]

I want to move that button elsewhere on the toolbar, so I open **View > Customize Toolbar...** and drag it to where I want it. The other toolbar controls move to make way for the new spot, but when I drop it, nothing changes; the Downloads button returns to its original position.

Interestingly, I don't have this problem on Safari 5.1 on Windows; I can move the button anywhere I want. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with these observations:

- The list of downloads appears as a window on Windows, but as a popover on OS X.
- The Downloads button appears by itself in the Customize Toolbar window on Windows, but not on OS X, where it only appears in the default toolbar set instead.

How can I reposition the Downloads button in Safari on OS X?

Comment: Until they fix it, you can't.

Comment: @Gerry: So it's a bug?

Comment: I'd say so, but it's not officially confirmed afaik. Always the remote possibility it is a 'feature'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drag the other controls around it; as long as you don’t grab the Downloads button itself this will work.

Comment: Yep, it works. Makes it seem even more of a bug that I can't drag the button itself.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I managed it—look at the picture above! Right-click → Customise Toolbar and move the URL bar out, then move it back in on the right.

Comment: Please explain how you did that.

Comment: I can confirm that this still works in Safari 12.1.2 - trying to move the downloads button was driving me mad, but by moving the URL field to the right of the downloads button instead of trying to move the downloads button to the left worked perfectly.